# Issue with Parser

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am training an AI but I am getting this error and cant figure out why.

usage: car.py [-h] [--dataset /path/to/car/dataset/] --weights /path/to/weights.h5 [--logs /path/to/logs/] [--image path or URL to image] [--video path or URL to video] 
car.py: error: the following arguments are required: , --weights

this is my parser

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
import argparse

# Parse command line arguments
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description='Train Mask R-CNN to detect cars.')
parser.add_argument("command",
                    metavar="<command>",
                    help="'train' or 'splash'")
parser.add_argument('--dataset', required=False,
                    metavar="/path/to/car/dataset/",
                    help='Directory of the Car dataset')
parser.add_argument('--weights', required=True,
                    metavar="/path/to/weights.h5",
                    help="Path to weights .h5 file or 'coco'")
parser.add_argument('--logs', required=False,
                    default=DEFAULT_LOGS_DIR,
                    metavar="/path/to/logs/",
                    help='Logs and checkpoints directory (default=logs/)')
parser.add_argument('--image', required=False,
                    metavar="path or URL to image",
                    help='Image to apply the color splash effect on')
parser.add_argument('--video', required=False,
                    metavar="path or URL to video",
                    help='Video to apply the color splash effect on')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Comment: How are you invoking the scrip from the command line? Looks like you're not passing an argument for `--weights`, but you marked `--weights` as a required argument.

Answer (score 0):

The error says that your weights argument is required, and you yourself have written so in your code. It won't run until you provide the argument `--weights` in your call